# Gridview linkbuttons not firing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have an ASP.Net page that has a gridview inside an update panel. When I run the application on the server, the gridview works perfectly fine. I'm able to select the row and display the information in a detailsview and I'm also able to delete directly on the gridview.

However, when I host the page and try to access it externally, none of the linkbuttons on the gridview work (the paging, the sorting, Select and Delete), the page is just static. This happens with all browsers (Safari, IE, Firefox, Chrome)

I tried checking with firebug to see what the issue is, and this is what I get:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 
An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

 case "error":
this._endPostBack(this._createPageRequestManagerServerError(Number.parseInvariant(deltaNode.id), deltaNode.content), executor, null);
return null;
case "pageTitle":
document.title = deltaNode.content;
break;
```

Can someone please explain to me what could cause this to happen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's an asynchronous postback error.  You're going to have to attach to [the AsyncPostBackError event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbackerror.aspx), log the error so you can access it, and see for yourself what is causing it.  This event handler catches all async errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

as the error code is 500, so there some thing wrong on the server side, Look into the Windows event logs, the IIS logs and find what is the issue

check this article for [ajax error handling](http://encosia.com/how-to-improve-aspnet-ajax-error-handling/)